# TYPO3 - includelibs security

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I need to include a PHP script in my TS template :

```
page {

  10 = USER_INT
  10.includeLibs = lib_confidential.php
  10.userFunc = MyClass->ConfidentialRequest

}
```

It works perfectly but I would like to locate the lib_confidential.php outside of my website root directory (and make something like `10.includeLibs = ../lib_confidential.php`). Is it possible to secure my PHP script and how to ? I thought about creating a symlink but that doesn't give any solution.

Comment: You can place your user function file in your extension too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your installation needs an update you will have to change the mechanism for including php-functions for the future.
since TYPO3 8 you need to have a class for your php functions. So the autoloader can identify the class and execute the function you need to place the class inside of an extension or declare the class to the autoloader.

Best practice would be site extension where you configure your installation, there you can havea class with all the functions you need.

examples can be found in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bernd, I have no extension for to host the PHP class for nom but you're right : it seems to be the most secured way to do what I want.

Comment: you always can add an minimum extension with ext_emconf.php an icon and your class